# Using ACTION_SCREEN_ON weird behavior on notifications

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, screen

I got a broadcast receiver that gets if a screen was turned on, and pops up an activity.

However when the screen is turned on, by a notification(mainly calls) the activity will try to get called but will be blocked by the lock screen, and the call will be put as a notification, instead of being the screen to try to answer the call.

Is there a way to make my broadcast receiver only recognize if the lock screen has been opened?

my broadcast receiver looks lie this now.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    BroadcastReceiver bd;
    public MyService() {
    }

    class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Intent startupIntent = new Intent(context, ScreenJump.class);
            startupIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(startupIntent);
        }
        public ScreenReceiver()
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        bd = new ScreenReceiver();
        registerReceiver(bd, filter);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT

Broadcast Action: Sent when the user is present after device wakes up (e.g when the keyguard is gone).
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_USER_PRESENT